# Avoid bitmap from being recycled automatically - Android

Tags: java, android, bitmap, drawing, screenshot

I am capturing screen whenever the screen is being touched and i am saving bitmaps in the ArrayList.

```
screen.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
            count++;
            screen.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
            screen.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

            Bitmap b = screen.getDrawingCache();
            bitmapList.add(b);
            Log.e("Captured Image Number: ", ""+count);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

And afterwards when i try to access the bitmaps to save them, they are no more there, recycled!
What should i do?
If i save here, it takes very long time.
Tried to convert into `byte[]` to avoid recycling, it also took long then expected.
I want to keep it upto 15fps what should i do.

Comment: One thing to try would be storing a copy of each Bitmap into array. Using Bitmap.copy(config, true).

Comment: @harsim tried it too... Had no luck, recycled.

Answer (score 0):

Store the bitmap in a class level variable instead of temp var. It should not be recycled if your screen is still live and your screen holds a hard reference to the bitmap object.

Answer (score 0):

This might be too late. But since there is no proper answer to this yet, I'd like to post my workaround for this issue. I tried harism's answer and it needs to be used like this.

So if you have an array-list of bitmaps, first you need to save a copy of the bitmap using `Bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config config, boolean isMutable)` method.

Then when you are going to using the bitmap, do not directly use the bitmap, instead get a copy of the bitmap using the same copy method, and that copied bitmap should be used in your application.

The bottom line is once a bitmap is used multiple times, it will be recycled.So what I have done is to avoid using the original bitmap, I take copies of the original bitmap and use them.